# Using different versions of Python

Tags: linux, software-installation, python

**Background**:

Since I develop python programs that must run on different python versions, I have installed different versions of python on my computer.

I am using FC 13 so it came with python 2.6 pre-installed in `/usr/bin/python2.6` and `/usr/lib/python2.6`.

I installed python 2.5 from source, and to keep things neat, I used the `--prefix=/usr` option, which installed python in `/usr/bin/python2.5` and `/usr/lib/python2.5`.

Now, when I run `python` my prompt shows I am using version 2.5. However, I am having some issues with the install.

**Package management**:

Using easy_install, packages are always installed in `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. I downloaded `setuptools` .egg for python 2.5 and tried to install it, but it gives me an error:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages does NOT support .pth files
```

It seems that python2.5 is not in my PYTHONPATH. I thought the default install would add itself to the PYTHONPATH, but when I write `echo $PYTHONPATH` at promt, I just receive an empty line.

Comment: I found out this beauty: [pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The recommended way of having multiple Python versions installed is to install each from source - they will happily coexist together. You can then use virtualenv with the appropriate interpreter to install the required dependencies (using pip or easy_install). The trick to easier installation of multiple interpreters from source is to use:

```
sudo make altinstall
```

instead of the more usual "sudo make install". This will add the version number to the executable (so you'd have python-2.5, python-2.6, python-3.2 etc) thus preventing any conflicts with the system version of Python.

Comment: Altinstall + virtualenv = python development nirvahna. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This sounds like a perfect application for [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), a very popular tool for creating isolated Python environments. This is a sample command to specify the version of Python

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 myvirtualenv
```

Comment: I don't think `virtualenv` is the solution in this case. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

> Using `easy_install`, packages are always installed in
>   `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`

That's because distutils adds shebang line to all scripts being installed. If you run `easy_install` script directly it gets executed with the interpreter it was installed with (according to shebang line). Which `easy_install` is being run depends on your `PATH` not `PYTHONPATH`. If you want to install a package in Python 2.5 instance you should run `easy_install` specifying Python interpreter to use:

```
/usr/bin/python2.5/python easy_install ...
```

Strictly speaking `virtualenv` doesn't help here as it must be created in the context of *base* Python which is exactly the same problem as with running `easy_install`. That's what `--python` argument of `virtualenv` is for. For some reason `easy_install` does not provide analogous argument so it must be run with specific Python interpreter as shown above.

Comment: It's my first answer here and I hope the first Necromancer badge as well :)

Comment: Very good explanation, thank you! Necromancer badge well earned ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using Fedora 13 and `PYTHONPATH` is not set.

Within python, `sys.path` will give you a list of the paths used for importing scripts.

I'm not familiar with how `easy_install` decides its destination directory but I'm sure there would be a command line argument you could give it.

Try specifying which python version to run `easy_install` under by preceding your command with the full path to the python you want.

Also check if `easy_install` is a symlink in bin to a script within one python version you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv is definitely a godsend here.

In my setup, I have environment variable `VIRTUALENV_USE_DISTRIBUTE` set to 1, so that the more modern Distribute package is used instead of setuptools.  I created virtual environments for the two versions of Python on my system like so:

```
$ virtualenv -p python2.6 py2
$ virtualenv -p python3.2 py3
```

I then created three aliases in `.bashrc`:

```
alias py2='source $HOME/py2/bin/activate'
alias py3='source $HOME/py3/bin/activate'
alias idle='python -m idlelib.idle'
```

Thus I can use `py2` to switch to a default of Python 2.6 and `py3` to switch to a default of Python 3.2. Entering `idle` will run whichever version of IDLE is appropriate for the virtual environment I am in.

Installation of packages into one of these virtual environments usually just involves a `pip install` command.