# Installing python modules for python2.6

Tags: centos, python

On my CentOS 5.8 system (el5 , 64bit), I had python2.4 after OS install and I installed python2.6 now. Now I want to install python modules using `yum`.

But whenever I install a new python module it "goes" to the python2.4 and is not installed for python2.6.

I tried to replace the python2.4 binary with python2.6 binary. But this broke `yum` and I had to restore python2.4. So I concluded that it is not a good idea to uninstall python2.4 (that came with base OS) as it might break other system dependencies.

My question is how do I safely install python modules targeting python2.6 without breaking python2.4?

Comment: You can try PIP or easy_install instead of yum.

Comment: I tried that already. But yum install `easy_install2.4` !

Comment: If you installed python26 from EPEL, there are 2.6 modules available there.

Comment: @jordanm Yes. I did install Python2.6 from EPEL and both Python2.4 & Python2.6 are there in my system currently and they are working fine with no issues. My problem is that when I install any python module (using yum or easy_install) it goes "under" python2.4 (that came with the centOS). 
Hence the installed python modules are not available to python2.6 which is the python version I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but answering in case others come across this. The easiest way to install modules for a specific version of python that is not set as your default would be like this:

```
pip2.6 install <name of python module>
```

The above example is assuming 2.6, but of course you could change it to 3.2, 2.7, whatever you are targeting.

Enjoy

Comment: A downside to this is that the modules are installed past the systems package managament systems, so e.g. `yum` isn't able to manage updates and removal. If a module is only needed for a particular user, `pip2.6 install --user <module>` installs the module using the user scheme to `~/.local/lib/python2.6`.

Answer (score 0):

First related question on the right:

[Using different versions of Python](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/using-different-versions-of-python?rq=1)

To quote vperic directly:

"The recommended way of having multiple Python versions installed is to install each from source - they will happily coexist together. You can then use virtualenv with the appropriate interpreter to install the required dependencies (using pip or easy_install). The trick to easier installation of multiple interpreters from source is to use:

sudo make altinstall
instead of the more usual "sudo make install". This will add the version number to the executable (so you'd have python-2.5, python-2.6, python-3.2 etc) thus preventing any conflicts with the system version of Python." and

This sounds like a perfect application for virtualenv, a very popular tool for creating isolated Python environments. This is a sample command to specify the version of Python

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 myvirtualenv
```

Comment: My problem is not working with multiple python versions. They are working fine. But the default is python2.4 and any installation of python module links to python2.4. But I don't want that. I want the modules to under python2.6.

Answer (score 0):

The EPEL provides 2.6 versions of some modules. These modules will always have 26 in the name. Here is an example package name: `python26-numpy`.

For modules that do not come from `RPM`, you can run the build system with the correct python binary.

```
python2.6 setup.py install
```

This will install the module for your 2.6 installation.

Comment: This is a way. But I needed to install a lot of python modules for running a python software, lets call it X. I don't know much about X and I don't even have the list of python modules X would need. I plan to resolve as & when an import error pops up. So I can't download all such modules and build rpm and install them. Instead if I can `yum` to install modules "under" python2.6, I can avoid all these & do `yum install ...` whenever I hit an error. But if my search on internet(it goes on & on) and SO doesn't help me, will eventually have to do in this horrible way:( +1 for your time anyway :)

Comment: @KingsIndian If you have EPEL enabled, you don't need to download the RPM manually. `yum install python26-numpy` for example.

Comment: Oh I see. That's nice. I have already EPEL5 enabled it btw. But I am not sure if all the modules I needed are there in EPEL5. I'll try that out.